# Multidimensional arrays to chessboard within C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have a multidimensional array with 5 rows and 2 columns. What I need to do now is output each element as a chessboard field. Furthermore, I need only the white fields.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int a[5][2] = {{0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6},{4,8}};

   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
      for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
      {
         cout << a[i] << "\n" << a[j] << endl;
      }

   return 0;
}
```

Do I just increment in one of the loops with +1 so that I escape the black fields? Because if so I kinda get confused as to which elements have to be skipped.

Expected output:

`1 2 3 4 5 6
  7 8 9 1 2`

Tidied like that.

Comment: Chessboards are generally 8x8. Even if you're only outputting the white ones, you're missing a lot.

Comment: If you are confused as to what to increment and when, then only operate on fields for which `(row + col) % 2 == 0` (or `!= 0`, depending on whether you want the white or the black cells.)

Comment: Could you explain what the expected output is given this program?  It is a bit unclear.

Comment: Updated OP with a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather unique solution (assuming the first square is white):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int a[5][2] = {{0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6},{4,8}};

   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
      {
         // Check for white square by checking if the sum of the index is "even"
         if((i + j) % 2 == 0)
         {
             cout << a[i][j] << endl;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Note: It would be fairly easy to change to the case if the first square is black, but I will leave that for you to figure out :-)

Note 2: It would be fairly easy to turn this into a function to handle a chess board of any (positive) size.

Comment: I get the idea but `cout << a[i] << "\n" << a[j] << endl;` is kinda wrong. I messed it back up in my code.

Comment: @dwvaxaz I missed that when I copied and pasted your code, I corrected it now.